# How could I change the port of target host?

Tags: php, soap

I need send a request using soapclient  but I'm not able to change the port of target, if i try to send it addreses like "192.168.1.1:60000" I got the error "Error Fetching http headers".

my code:

```
    $this->client = new SoapClient($wsdlPath, array(
        'trace' => 1, 
        'exceptions' => true, 
        'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true
        ),
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2
    ));

$this->client->__setLocation($deviceAddr);      

$this->client->__setSoapHeaders($this->soapClientWSSecurityHeader($user,$pass));
```

Comment: unless you control the target machine you cannot simply elect to send to a different port and hope for it to work

Comment: I think it's not clear enough for you @RamRaider, the port that I want to send the soap request is listenning, my problem is i don't know exaclty how to change de default port in soap client to send it for a diferent port than the default port (80).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355366/how-to-specify-port-name-in-php-wsdl/30540895 might be of interest?

Comment: You just put it in the url `http://example.com:1580` et.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix when i tryed this i got an error  ... "Error Fetching http headers"